# Since $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are not homeomorphic, does that mean the cardinality of $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are different?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, cardinals, real-numbers, isometry

Given $[0,1]$ a closed interval on $\mathbb{R}$, we know that $[0,1]$ is compact and $\mathbb{R}$ is not, so these two spaces are not homeomorphic to each other.

But homeomorphic perserves cardinality. Since there is no homeomorphism, does that mean the cardinality are diferent between the two sets?

Comment: 'a implies b' is not the same as 'b implies a'.

Comment: There *is* a homeomorphism between (0,1) and $\mathbb{R}$, so their cardinalities are the same. [0,1] is a proper superset of one and subset of the other, so they must all have the same cardinality.

Comment: No. Homeomorphisms are bijections, but not all bijections are homeomorphisms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cardinalities of two sets $X$ and $Y$ are the same iff there exists a bijection between them.

The topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic iff there exists a bijection between them that is continuous in both directions.

As you can see, homeomorphicity is a much stricter requirement, so it shouldn't come as a surprise that there are sets that have the same cardinality without being homeomorphic.

Comment: Is there a quick way to show bijection between closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @EmotionallyVulnerableLlama: Not if you consider the closed subset $\{42\}$.

Comment: @EmotionallyVulnerableLlama the cardinality of a set and whether it's open or closed have very little to nothing in common.

Comment: @EmotionallyVulnerableLlama if the closed subset contains an open interval, this can be done by using the recursive proof of the [Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem). In general, this is difficult, and the proof is given by the Cantor-Bendixson theorem.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Why would obvious things be so difficult to proove

Comment: @EmotionallyVulnerableLlama because closed sets can be complicated; indeed, the last theorem doesn't give you an explicit bijection.

Answer (score 6):

$f: X \to Y$ homeomorphism $\implies$ $f:X \to Y$ bijective $\implies$ $\vert X \vert=\vert Y\vert$ but the converse does not hold in general. To see that use your counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

When considering the question of whether two sets are homeomorphic, we want to make sure that our map is a bijection, but also that it is continuous and has a continuous inverse.

These sets actually have the same cardinality, you can verify this by checking that $\mathbb{R}$~$(0,1)$~$[0,1]$ using the schroeder-bernstein theorem.

The issue arises when considering topological invariants like compactness. By the heine-borel theorem, every closed and bounded subset of euclidean space is compact. $[0,1]$, is both closed and bounded, while $\mathbb{R}$ is unbounded, and hence not compact. Since the continuous image of a compact set must be compact, we cannot have a continous bijection from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether two sets $A,B$ have the same cardinality, you have to just check whether there are injections $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$. If there is, then there exists a bijection $h:A\to B$ which ensures that the two sets have the same cardinality, that is [Schroder's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem). There is no topological structure at play when it comes to checking cardinality, the bare set structure is enough. So you do not need homeomorphism.

For the two sets $A=[0,1]$ and $B=\mathbb{R}$, it is easy to find two such injections, namely $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=1/(1+e^x)$.

Comment: I agree with your exposition, except that $g$ is not injective: $g(-x)=g(x)$. I propose the alternative example $g(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(x) + \frac12$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Corrected it @GiuseppeNegro.